# Как сделать плитку изображений как ВКонтакте?

Tags: java, android

Хочу реализовать что-то вроде grid'а. Пробовал с gridView. Не понял как работает. Ибо нужно чтобы оно само понимало, что нужно сместить, растянуть и так далее. Есть идеи? Или может есть готовые библиотеки? Приложил фото примера, как хочется реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

За отрисовку `View` в `RecyclerView` отвечает `LayoutManager`. У вас есть два пути:

- Простой - найти библиотеку, вроде [этой](https://github.com/android/plaid/tree/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8) или [этой](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). Можете так же погуглить альтернативы по запросу: *"Assymetrical Grid Layout"*
- Сложный - самому написать свой `LayoutManager`. Вы получите больше контроля над вашим RecyclerView, но это прямо скажу задача не тривиальная. Вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/true_engineering/blog/267497/) и [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/434024/) есть неплохие статьи как это сделать.